# Where is the source code of GHC's language extension: "Arrows"?

Tags: haskell, ghc, arrows

Where can i find the source code, that hides behind the language pragma

```
{-# LANGUAGE Arrows #-}
```

I've read the according papers (like [Paterson, A New Notation for Arrows](http://www.soi.city.ac.uk/~ross/papers/notation.html)) , so what theoretically happens is clear. Now i want to see, how this is actually translated into source code.

All my search leads only to GHC's User Guide or the source of Control.Arrow.
Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think [this](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/master/compiler/deSugar/DsArrows.lhs) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Just to be clear: LANGUAGE Arrows only turns on the desugaring for the Arrow do-notation. If you want to conceptually understand arrows by looking at the source, you're better off looking at the source for the Control.Category and Control.Arrow modules, and at some instantiations of the Arrow typeclass.